# Regex notepad++ replace first character only

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have been going through some examples of similar questions here on how to find first character in data to replace with another character. This is the column delimiter in our data and I need to change this.

One of the examples did manage to replace the first comma however on setting replace all it looped round to the start and started replacing commas in the actual data in 2nd column, which I didn't want.

The first column of data doesn't have any other characters in it to worry about as it is ID column. I need to build a regex that identifies the first comma and then something to replace it with but without looping round to the start of the data and replacing more commas.

I've tried starting small and building up. I started with this and it finds the first comma in each row but also highlights the character before it, which I think needs tweaking.

([^,]);

I've not found a post or help on exactly what I want to do so I am trying to stick bits of various examples together from different topics, which is working in one way but adding additional functionality which I do not want.

Any help or suggestions on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: You mean you want to replace the first `,` in the document when clicking *Replace all*? Looks like `^([^,]*),([\s\S]*)` --> `$1$2` should work then.

Comment: Or, `,(.*)` --> `$1` with *`.` matches newline* on.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `([^,]);` with Replace All, it will remove all chars other than `,` and the subsequent `;`, all these occurrences.

If you want to match just the first `,` enable the *`.` matches newline*, and use

```
,(.*)
```

regex pattern to replace with `$1` (if you want to remove), or `:$1` (to, say, replace with  a colon). If you do not want to mess with options in the UI, you may pass the DOTALL modifier as the inline option to the pattern: `(?s),(.*)`.

[image]